# Is it possible to join data frames using something like full_join in R without duplicating column values

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to combine to payment streams by date, however when I use full_join it duplicates some payment streams, making analysis impossible.

For Example when I run this code with example data:

```
library(tidyquant)

v1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c")
v2 = c(1,2,3,4,3,4)

v3 = c("a", "b", "c")
v4 = c(10,20,30)

df1 = data.frame(v1, v2)
df2 = data.frame(v3, v4)

full_join(df1, df2, by = c("v1" = "v3"))
```

I get this output:

```
  v1 v2 v4
1  a  1 10
2  a  2 10
3  b  3 20
4  b  4 20
5  c  3 30
6  c  4 30
```

But I want this:

```
  v1 v2 v4
1  a  1 10
2  a  2 NA
3  b  3 20
4  b  4 NA
5  c  3 30
6  c  4 NA
```

Is there any way, using dplyrs join or other functions to get the output I want.

Comment: youa re joining on v1=v3.. so it is expected behaviour that all a's get value 10.

Comment: I hear you, but is there any way using join or otherwise to join without duplicating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
#convert to data.table format
setDT(df1); setDT(df2)
#update join non-duplicated v1-values
df1[!duplicated(v1), v4 := df2[df1[!duplicated(v1),], v4, on = .(v3 = v1)]]

#    v1 v2 v4
# 1:  a  1 10
# 2:  a  2 NA
# 3:  b  3 20
# 4:  b  4 NA
# 5:  c  3 30
# 6:  c  4 NA
```